# Rearrange the javascript object structure

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I want to rearrange the structure of an object and I am stuck since yesterday, so I need your important assistance.

Currently, the structure looks like:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 14,
    language: "english",
    title: "I am a new article",
    bodyText: "Article Content",
    lang: "eng",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    language: "greeks",
    title: "Ειμαι ενα καινουρειο αρθρο",
    bodyText: "Κυριο μερος Αρθρου",
    lang: "gr",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    language: "espanol",
    title: "Soy un nuevo articulo",
    bodyText: "Soy un nuevo articulo",
    lang: "es",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  },

]
```

I want to rearrange the structure to the following format:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  language: {
    es: {
      title: "Spanish Article",
      bodyText: "Content in Spanish"
    },
    gr: {

      title: "Greek Article",
      bodyText: "Content in Grecce"
    }
  },
  id: 2,
  language: {
    en: {
      title: "English Article",
      bodyText: "Content in English"
    }
  }
}];
```

I have written the following code to achieve the task but without luck.

```js
var arr = [];
let result = data.reduce(function(c, v) {
  console.log(v.id);
  /*   console.log(c);
   */
  c[v.id] = c[v.id] || {};
  c[v.id][v.lang] = c[v.id][v.lang] || {
    title: v.title,
    bodyText: v.bodyText,
    keywords: v.keywords
  };
  arr.push(c)
  return c;
}, {});
console.log(arr);
```

I get an object like the following:

```js
[{
id:1,
es:{
title:"Spanish Article",
bodyText:"Content in Spanish"
},
gr:{
title:"Greek Article",
bodyText:"Content in Grecce"
},
id:2,
en:{
title:"English Article",
bodyText:"Content in English"
}
}]
```

Any recommendation is welcome, thanks to the community in advance!

Comment: What does "without luck" mean?  What is or is not working?

Comment: The two objects don't share anything in common, your example seems artificial.  And the "target" structure is inconsistent - what's the `id` _within_ the `gr` key about?

Comment: The expected output has has just one object with 2 keys called `id`. Do you want an array of different objects? Please create a [mcve] with a valid expected output

Comment: One article is translated into different languages. So I want to group the articles by the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target data model seems a bit suboptimal, because you have an array with unique ids that could be more performant as a Object with the id as keys, but you can get away with your data model as well:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 14,
    language: "english",
    title: "I am a new article",
    bodyText: "Article Content",
    lang: "eng",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    language: "greeks",
    title: "Ειμαι ενα καινουρειο αρθρο",
    bodyText: "Κυριο μερος Αρθρου",
    lang: "gr",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    language: "espanol",
    title: "Soy un nuevo articulo",
    bodyText: "Soy un nuevo articulo",
    lang: "es",
    keywords: ["key1", "key2"]
  }
];
  
console.log(data.reduce(function(result, entry) {
  var id_index = result.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(entry.id);
  var id_element;
  
  if (id_index === -1) {
    id_element = {id: entry.id, language: {}};
  } else {
    id_element = result[id_index];
  }
  
  id_element.language[entry.lang] = {
    title: entry.title,
    bodyText: entry.bodyText
  };
  
  if (id_index === -1) {
    result.push(id_element);
  }
  
  return result;
}, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the properties and use later the values from the hash table.

The main part is to take an intitial object with a `language` property.

```js
var data = [{ id: 14, language: "english", title: "I am a new article", bodyText: "Article Content", lang: "eng", keywords: ["key1", "key2"] }, { id: 1, language: "greeks", title: "Ειμαι ενα καινουρειο αρθρο", bodyText: "Κυριο μερος Αρθρου", lang: "gr", keywords: ["key1", "key2"] }, { id: 1, language: "espanol", title: "Soy un nuevo articulo", bodyText: "Soy un nuevo articulo",     lang: "es", keywords: ["key1", "key2"] }],
    result = data.reduce((c, { id, lang, title, bodyText, keywords }) => {
        c[id] = c[id] || { id, language: {} };
        c[id].language[lang] = { title, bodyText, keywords };
        return c;
    }, {}),
    array = Object.values(result);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```